# WPF binding not being set to UserControl DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a ListView which is bound to a list of objects. When I select an item in the ListView, I catch a `SelectionChanged` event and then pass the selected object off to a details view.

```
protected void list_selectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    var myObject = theList.SelectedItem as MyObjectType;

    detailsView.DataContext = myObject;
}
```

detailsView is a UserControl in the same WPF as the ListView. It contains some XAML like so:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=deviceId}"></Label>
<l:MyUc deviceId="{Binding Path=deviceId}" />
```

Inside MyUC, I've got a DependencyProperty defined:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty deviceIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("deviceId", typeof(Guid), typeof(MyUC), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

public Guid deviceId {
    get { return (Guid)GetValue(deviceIdProperty); }
    set { SetValue(deviceIdProperty, value); }
}
```

The Label shows the deviceId, but the property inside MyUC never gets set.

Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: InotifyPropertyChanged i suppose issue. in set function a PropertyChanged event should be raised

Comment: if you copy/pasted your code, I'd say the problem might be that you need a capital P in the second line of your xaml (second portion of code)

Comment: @iltzortz I've actually got a breakpoint in the set of that property and it never gets called.

Comment: @ppetrov Thanks, that was a problem in the creation of the question. Actual code is properly capitalized.

Comment: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null)); perhaps try SqlGuid.Null instead of just null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a Dependency Property in XAML, the set method never gets called.  If you want to "see" this set, you need to add a property changed callback, as the binding mechanism directly sets the dependency property without your setter.

For details on how to implement this, see the [PropertyChanged callbacks section of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx#Coerce_Value_Callbacks_and_Property_Changed_Events).

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be helpful if you could add the actual XAML code where you define the ListView and it's properties.

Second, you should look at the output console (in Visual Studio debug session of course) and see whether there are binding errors regarding the bindings you defined.

It is very probable that the bindings provide values that does not fit the deviceId dependency property type and thus it never changes.